# Dynamically specify column name in spread()

Tags: r, tidyr

I am attempting to automate a simple process of importing some data and using the spread function from the tidyr package to make it wide format data.

Below is a simplified example

```
Ticker <- c(rep("GOOG",5), rep("AAPL",5))
Prices <- rnorm(10, 95, 5)

Date <- rep(sapply(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05"),as.Date), 2)

exStockData <- data.frame(Ticker, Date, Prices)
```

After reading in a data frame like exStockData, I'd like to be able to create a data frame like the one below

```
library(tidyr)
#this is the data frame I'd like to be able to create
desiredDataFrame <- spread(exStockData, Ticker, Prices)
```

However, the column used for the key argument of the spread function will not always be called Ticker and the column used for the value argument of the function will not always be called Prices. The column names are read in from a different portion of the file that gets imported.

```
#these vectors are removed because the way my text file is read in 
#I don't actually have these vectors
rm(Ticker, Prices, Date)

#the name of the first column (which serves as the key in 
#the spread function) of the exStockData data frame will 
#vary, and is read in from the file and stored as a one 
#element character vector
secID <- "Ticker"

#the name of the last column in the data frame 
#(which serves as the value in the spread function) 
#is stored also stored as a one element character vector
fields <- "Prices"

#I'd like to be able to dynamically specify the column 
#names using these other character vectors
givesAnError <- spread(exStockData, get(secID), get(fields))
```

Comment: The documentation for `?spread` refers you to `?spread_` which is specifically for this purpose.

Comment: That is both handy and embarrassing at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: @user1583016, you can either post the solution as an answer to your own question and accept it, or delete the question. This is documented in the help files and as part of the vignettes, if I'm not mistaken. (Unless joran wants to post the answer....)

Comment: I went ahead and posted the answer. I can't accept it for another two days though.

Answer (score 1):

The "See also" section of the documentation for the spread function mentions the spread_ function which is intended to be used in this situation.

In this case the solution is to use:

```
solved <- spread_(exstockData, secID, fields)
```